# RUN dotnet lambda package - causes Invalid Argument error when run twice on CI

Tags: .net, docker, aws-lambda, docker-compose

#### Setup

- I'm running a `build.cake` file.
- The Cake file has two steps `DockerComposeUp` and then `IntegrationTests`.
- `docker-compose.yml` spins up a localstack instance from a `Dockerfile` with two lambdas packaged with `RUN dotnet lambda package` steps.
- Runnning cake locally works fine for both Windows and Mac development environments, containers spin up and tests all pass, logs get emitted.
- Running from a GHA (Custom runner) it fails the second `dotnet lambda package` (regardless of order).

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS lambdabuild

# install lambda tools
RUN dotnet tool install -g Amazon.Lambda.Tools
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.dotnet/tools"

# install zip
RUN apt update
RUN apt -y install zip

# build and zip lambdas
COPY ./src/ ./src/
COPY ./nuget.config ./

# Second line always fails on CI.
RUN dotnet lambda package -pl ./src/Services.TestProcessor/ ./bin/testprocessor.zip
RUN dotnet lambda package -pl ./src/Services.SourceConsumer/ ./bin/sourceconsumer.zip

FROM localstack/localstack:latest
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get install dos2unix

# copy over lambda zips
COPY --from=lambdabuild /bin/. /docker/lambdas/

# Add init file
ADD ./docker-setup/localstack/init.sh /etc/localstack/init/ready.d/

# etc
```

#### Error

```
[services_localstack lambdabuild 8/8] RUN dotnet lambda package -pl ./src/Services.SourceConsumer/ ./bin/sourceconsumer.zip:
failed to solve: failed to prepare ylke4uhhfxeart4kxrl44qax0: invalid argument
```

#### Investigation

I've maxed out the log verbosity for `Cake`, `Docker` and `GHA`, but the only error is the above message in the `DockerComposeUp` step of the cake file.

When I run this, the first `dotnet lambda package` succeeds, the second fails. If I swap the order, to `sourceconsumer` followed by `testprocessor`, then `testprocessor` fails. If I remove one, the `DockerComposeUp` step completes succesfully, but the `IntegrationTests` fail because of missing dependencies.

This problem is also present when running `RUN dotnet test` against the two projects.

```
RUN dotnet test ./test/Services.UnitTests/
RUN dotnet test ./test/Services.TestProcessor.UnitTests/
```

First line succeeds, second line fails, again regardless of order, and also with `invalid argument`

I'm in the process of getting hold of the `GHA` runner image, because I think it could be something environmental, but i'm not sure where to dig next. Any thoughts on what could be going on here?

#### Investigation Update

This seems to be a problem running any sequential step of `RUN dotnet {command}`. Second step always fails with invalid argument, I have mixed up `RUN dotnet restore`, `RUN dotnet test` and `RUN dotnet lambda package -pl`. As long as there are no runtime errors in step 1, step 2 will always fail with Invalid Argument.
I have also tried with both `dotnet 6` and `dotnet 7` which has no effect.

#### Investigation Update 2

This seems to only affect the second execution of `RUN` after running a `RUN dotnet {command}` step. Eg:

```
# Passes
RUN echo "Pre"

# Passes
RUN dotnet lambda package -pl ./src/Services.SourceConsumer/ ./bin/sourceconsumer.zip 

# Fails (Invalid Argument)
RUN echo "Post"
```

I'm beginning to wonder if there is some kind of encoding causing a phantom symbol to be written to the command line that corrupts the next execution of `RUN`.

Comment: Check if folder names are correct inside the ./src/. Especially the case sensitivity. On Windows it doesn't matter, but on Linux (Docker is Linux based) it's a huge difference.

Comment: I'd expect that to fail on everything, rather than succeed once, then fail.

Comment: Any updates there for possible reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what caused the original problem, but the workaround for this issue was as follows:

Move the two `RUN` steps into a bash file `lambda-package.sh`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
dotnet lambda package -pl ./src/Services.SourceConsumer/ ./bin/sourceconsumer.zip
dotnet lambda package -pl ./src/Services.TestProcessor/ ./bin/testprocessor.zip
```

Replace the `RUN` steps in the `Dockerfile` with:

```
# Copy script to container root directory
COPY ./docker-setup/localstack/lambda-package.sh ./

# Make script executable
RUN chmod a+x lambda-package.sh

# Run script
RUN ./lambda-package.sh
```

From here, I've not had any problems adding lines to the `lambda-package.sh` for building additional lambda zip files.